# PHP bidimensional associative array of two different associative arrays how to foreach just one of the two

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-4

I'm in this situation because I have two associative arrays to pass to a view

Then in the view I have to foreach for the first array and get a list

and next foreach for the second and get a table of details

the array has been created this way which is slightly different than array_merge and others array_* functions

I just repeated twice the assignment in my code like this

```
    $newArray = $ticketResult;
    $newArray = $deptResult;
```

it works and print_r($newArray); shows this (follows after snippet):

```
    Array
    (
        [ticketResult] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3943
                        [t_name] => customerOne
                        [date] => 1508236987
                        [d_name] => In progress
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4139
                        [t_name] => AnotherName
                        [date] => 1522134694
                        [d_name] => In progress
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4367
                        [t_name] => HisName
                        [date] => 1535118892
                        [d_name] => On hold
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4395
                        [t_name] => Hername
                        [date] => 1536914668
                        [d_name] => Shipping
                    )

            )

        [deptResult] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 0
                        [name] => Arrived
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => In progress
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => On hold
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [name] => Closed
                    )

            )

    )
```

as you can see, two totally different associative arrays have been chained one after the other into the new associative array $newArray that in the next step I pass to a view (codeigniter)

Now in the view, I want to foreach the first 'ticketResult' for one purpose in a html table, as if it were a "single" associative array

then in another section of the view I want to foreach the other associative array 'ticketDept' to puti it in a list

I'm wondering how it is supposed to be done what I'd like to do...

How is supposed to be used this kind of bi-dimensional associative array made of two totally different associative arrays

I'm also open to better approaches to achieve my need , which originally is to pass two different arrays to the view, so if you think this issue can be differently addressed .. thank you for any suggestion

Thank you for hinting

For the sake of clarity this is the call in the controller

```
    return view("Ticketpage/showtickets", ['dataarrays' => $newArray]);
```

Comment: `foreach ($newArray['$newArray'] as $a) {` will just loop over that array ditto the other

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, sorry, can you kindly explicitly make the example of foreach e.g. just the 'ticketResult' array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Controller
$data = $ticketResult;
$data = $deptResult;

// view use the first array
<?php foreach($ticketResult as $result): ?>
  
 // Your code here

<?php endforeach; ?>




// view use the second array
<?php foreach($deptResult as $result): ?>
 
// Your code here

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However I would be a bit more explicit in the controller and do something like:

```
$data['ticketResult'] = $ticketResult['ticketResult'];
$data['deptResult'] = $deptResult['deptResult'];

// Then load the view
return view('foo/bar', $data);
```

Now let's say you want to display all the names of that ticket result in an unordered list. In your view you would do it like this:

```
 <ul>
 <?php foreach($deptResult as $result): ?>
    <li><?php echo $result['t_name'] ?></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: thank you. I have added at the end of my question the Controller call to the view. Can I kindly ask you to make the View side foreach more explicit? Thank you. On the View side I have 'dataarrays', how do I refer to one of the individual arrays in the view? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the double hint of Marco I finally ended with finding the correct technique to be applied

In the *Controller* I have two *associative* arrays returned by two methods of two different *Models*

As written in the question the two arrays are chained in the resulting array $data

```
public function showTickets($id)
{

    $ticketModel = new TicketModel();
    $deptModel = new DeptModel();

    $ticketRecords = $ticketModel->getTicketsByDept($id);
    $deptRecords = $deptModel->getAvailableDepts();

    $data['ticketResult'] = $ticketRecords;
    $data['deptResult'] = $deptRecords;

    return view("Chart/showtickets", $data);

}
```

and in the "showtickets" *View* , the two array are individually accessible this way

```
<h1>Chart</h1>

<p>

    <?php foreach ($deptRecord as $dKey): ?>

      <?= $dKey['id'] ?> , <?= $dKey['name'] ?> <br>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</p>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Ticket ID</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Data Creazione</th>
    <th>Dipartimento</th>
  </tr>

  <?php foreach ($ticketRecords as $tKey): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?= $tKey['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $tKey['t_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= date("d-m-Y", $tKey['date']) ?></td>
            <td><?= $tKey['d_name'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table> 


<?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

Comment: You dont need this: return view("Chart/showtickets", ['dataarray' => $data]); you can just send the $data to the view and they use the array keys as variables in the view.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro tried, doesn't work. I mean I tried passing `return view("Chart/showtickets", $data);`and in the view using  `<?php foreach ($data['deptResult'] as $dKey): ?> `

Comment: @marcogmonteiro ok I got it, thank you for the hint. I have edited the code.